# JavaScript Show/Hide Div not Opening

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am using a PHP while loop to display all of the rows in my table. Each row has a title and a description. I am trying to make a list of the titles with a link around each one. When the link is opened I am trying to make a div appear that displays the title and the description inside of the div. My problem is the divs are not appearing when links are hit.

**EDIT**: I am using the answer's JSFiddle as my code now, which utilizes jQuery. This code however still doesn't open up the divs.

Here is my full page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.light, .fade {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="noticeboard">
    <ul>
    <li><a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="clicklinkshow">title</a>
        <div class="light white_content">light<br /><br />description<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="clicklinkhide">Close</a></div>
        <div class="fade black_overlay">fade</div>
    </li>
    <li><a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="clicklinkshow">title</a>
        <div class="light white_content">light<br /><br />description<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="clicklinkhide">Close</a></div>
        <div class="fade black_overlay">fade</div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    $('.clicklinkshow').click(function() {
    $(this.parentNode).find('.light, .fade').show();
});

$('.clicklinkhide').click(function() {
    $(this.parentNode.parentNode).find('.light, .fade').hide();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection, which is an array-like object, not a single element.

Comment: Well there is multiple links being arrayed, so there would be multiple elements that have the same class name.

Comment: But the collection of elements doesn't implement the same interface as element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript:

```
// show
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('light'), function(el) {
 el.style.display='block'; 
});

// hide
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('light'), function(el) {
 el.style.display='none'; 
});
```

Jquery:

```
$('.light').show();
$('.light').hide();
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have updated the code in my question to what I currently have.

Comment: you can't use both, and you need to wrap this code inside a function, and then call this function inside the onclick event

Comment: jsfiddle with javascript only and inline event (deprecated): http://jsfiddle.net/4f2SB/

Comment: Jquery isnt working for some reason when I use it on my page. The divs are not appearing. I will see if I missed anything, the JavaScript version worked for me, although I am not going to use it because as you said it's deprecated.

Comment: only inline onclick is deprecated in favor or adding them with element.addEventListener('click', function() { ... }, false);

Comment: did you load jquery.js, and did you put the jquery code after the </ul> tag ?

Comment: I loaded jquery.js using this `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` after all of my stylesheet links. It is also the first JavaScript code I put in my page. I just put the jquery code after the </ul> tag and it still doesn't work.